# Authentication between to devices where the same password is used on both

Tags: authentication, passwords

I'm writing two applications that are intended for execution on two separate devices. It is similar to a remote desktop solution such as TeamViewer.

What follows below is my proposal for an authentication process between two devices A and B, where A is the authority. It may be a little verbose, but I just want to be thorough:

```
 1) User inputs a password to A
 2) A generates public and private key from password
 3) A saves private key to memory
 4) A saves private key to file
 5) A appends salt to password in memory
 6) A digests password + salt with SHA128.
 7) A saves the hash to file.

 8) B connects to A through TCP
 9) A sends public key to B
10) User inputs (the same) password to B
11) B encrypts password with the public key obtained from A
12) B sends the encrypted password to A
13) A decrypts the password with private key
14) A applies steps 5 and 6
15) A compares the hash of the obtained password with the stored hash.
```

This process doesn't involve sending the password in plain text over the network so that part is secure, so my questions are:

Should symmetric-key cryptography be used instead? If so, how would this be done without the plain-text password being transmitted?

It seems that storing both the hash of the password **and** the private key generated from the password is excessive. Is it?

On a side note, this all takes place over a LAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of one of those things that's terribly subjective.

What exactly are you trying to protect against here?

More questions that need answering:

- How does B verify that pub key received from A is the right key, and not a MITM key?
- How are you deriving a private key (pair) from the password?
- How are you blocking brute force attempts?
- What happens if someone gets the password hash and attempts to crack it offline?
- How are you protecting the private key file?
- How are you preventing replays of the encrypted password?

There are probably a few more questions worth asking that aren't listed as well.

The way you've outlined the flow is somewhat sound, but the implementation is a bit weak, and that's where you start getting into the don't-roll-your-own territory and that's never a good thing.

I would consider taking a look at how other similar systems handle authentication, or better yet use an existing protocol or technology that does this for you like Kerberos. Odds are pretty good most of those systems are already using pre-existing protocols.

Comment: "How does ... MITM key?" You just showed me why this can't work, thanks. I'll check Kerberos.